# Add category to single post page

Tags: php, wordpress

I've added to my single-post.php a code to display the post categories above the title, it looks good here: 
http://thenoirportrait.com/2014/08/23/review-chanel-perfection-lumiere-velvet/

But not here: 
http://thenoirportrait.com/2015/03/04/interior-design-black-home/

I have different post templates. What can I do to make the category change it's position with every post?

I think I should put my category code in the Archives.php but I'm not sure where. I don't want to mess up my code, any help is welcome.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
<div class="row<?php echo (($behind_title_fw) ? ' full-width' : ''); ?>">

      <div class="inner_content">

           <div class="row<?php echo (($has_sidebar) ? ' has-sidebar' : ''); ?>">

                <div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">

                <?php if($sidebar_below_title && !$is_endless_template) : ?>
                <div class="medium-12">

                   <?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
                   echo $category->cat_name . ' '; 
                    } 
                   ?>
                   <br>
                   <br>

                  <article id="post-header-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="article-header-above" data-postid="<?php echo esc_attr($post->ID); ?>" data-guid="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_guid($post->ID)); ?>" data-permalink="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>">
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The first post's class has a width of *12*:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="inner_content"> 
        <div class="row">   
            <div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
               REVIEWS <br><br>
               <div class="medium-12 column">
 ...
```

But the second one, a width of *8*:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="inner_content">
        <div class="row">
            <div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
               INTERIOR DESIGN<br><br>
            <div class="medium-8 column">
 ...
```

The key to align the second category (or whatever) is by putting it inside the `div` which defines the column size. Therefore, the category will be always center-aligned with the post:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="inner_content">
        <div class="row">
            <div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
                <div class="medium-8 column">
                   INTERIOR DESIGN<br><br>
 ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried to do that but no category appears.
I update my post to how my code looks right now

Comment: It was the same but without the category code: 
    <?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
                   echo $category->cat_name . ' '; 
                    } 
                   ?>
                   <br>
                   <br>

Comment: @TatianaH And where was the category printed before?

Comment: I was at the end of the post, but I hide it because it was next to the post tags, it was displaying like a tag.